Bigtable aggregated values
I'm trying to figure out how to use the Aggregate values at write time preview feature in Bigtable. The documentation states that this should be possible to do using the Java API, but there are a couple of things that I find confusing:

The documentation above states that I need to add an aggregate column family to the table. This implies that this is a special type of column family, but I can't find any way to specify a type, in Terraform or in the GUI.
The RowMutation class of the Java API does include an addToCell method that will do the sum aggregation, but I can't find any way to do the min and max aggregations listed in the documentation.


Update (mid-August 2024):

You do need to create typed column families to use this functionality, but there is still no way to to this in the GCP Console or using Terraform.
The Java API (google-cloud-bigtable version 2.42.0) now supports creating column families of all currently supported types (Sum, Min, Max, and HLL).
Regardless of the aggregation type, you will use RowMutation.addToCell whenever you want to update the value of an aggregated cell.

Previous state (end of July 2024):
At the time of writing (End of July 2024), this functionality is still incomplete (which kind of makes makes sense; it's still in preview after all). Since the documentation is lacking/incorrect and googling for answers has proven difficult I'm listing my findings here:

You do indeed need to create a column family of the Aggregate type. Currently, the only way to do this is using cbt (the Bigtable cli tool) or an API. There is no support in the Console or the GCP Terraform providers (GA or Beta). I've verified that it's possible to create a sum Aggregate column family using the Java API.
The min and max aggregation types are currently not supported in the Java API (google-cloud-bigtable version 2.41.0).

